# Not able to pass variables to private method using reflect package

Tags: java, reflection

I am trying to access private methods using reflect package. I am able to access private methods but I am facing problem to send arguments.

My code looks like:

```
Sample s = new Sample();
java.lang.reflect.Method method [] = Sample.class.getDeclaredMethods();
System.out.println("Total Number of methods in Sample class"+method.length);
for (int i=0; i<method.length;i++) {
    String methodName=method[i].getName();
    System.out.println("Method Name is "+methodName);
    if (methodName.equalsIgnoreCase("sampleTest1")) {
        method[i].setAccessible(true);
        //This is calling sampleTest1 method; it's not working
        //System.out.println(method[i].invoke(s, new String[]{"ABC"});
    } else {
        //This is calling sampleTest method and it's working
        System.out.println(method[i].invoke(s, null));
    }
}
```

My sample class:

```
public class Sample {
    private String sampleTest(){
         return "Private Method";
    }

    private String sampleTest1(String abc){
    return "Private Method";
    }
}
```

I am able to access the sampleTest() method but I don't know how to pass arguments to the sampleTest1() method. Can you please help in this?

#### OUTPUT

```
Total Number of methods in Sample class2

Method Name is sampleTest

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class com.sarma.reflection.sample.SampleTest can not access a member of class com.sarma.reflection.sample.Sample with modifiers "private"
    at sun.reflect.Reflection.ensureMemberAccess(Reflection.java:65)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:588)
    at com.sarma.reflection.sample.SampleTest.main(SampleTest.java:26)
```

Comment: `System.out.println(method[i].invoke(s, null)` is missing 1 `)`

Comment: How do you know sampleTest1() wasn't invoked? the end result for both is the same.

Comment: The code you've posted doesn't compile. Please fix it.

Comment: Missing an end parenthesis here: `System.out.println(method[i].invoke(s, null);`

Comment: Please stop changing your code. Previously the `else` was commented out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to cast the `null` argument you pass to `invoke()`.

```
 System.out.println(method[i].invoke(s, (Object)null));
```

Otherwise it thinks you are calling the underlying method with no arguments, ie. a `null` `Object[]`. By casting, the compiler (and runtime) knows you are passing a `null` object as the only element in the varargs `Object[]`.

After your edit: did you remove the `setAccessible(true)`? You've intertwined your `if-else`. Use

```
if(methodName.equalsIgnoreCase("sampleTest1")){
    method[i].setAccessible(true);
    System.out.println(method[i].invoke(s, (Object) null));
} else{
    method[i].setAccessible(true);
    System.out.println(method[i].invoke(s, null));
}
```

Or put the `method[i].setAccessible(true);` outside the `if-else`

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass an array of Object as the second argument to invoke():

```
method[i].invoke(s, new Object[] { "ABC" });
```

or with no arguments:

```
method[i].invoke(s, (Object[]) null);
```

Comment: With you no arguments you should leave out the `null`. This is cleaner `method[i].invoke(s)` ...and the IDE does not complain :)

Answer (score 1):

This should be a generic approach. We retrieve the methods parameters and create instances
of the same class, to pass as methods arguments.

```java
public class Sample
{
  @SuppressWarnings ("unused")
  private String sampleTest() { return "Private Method"; }

  @SuppressWarnings ("unused")
  private String sampleTest1(String s) { return "Private Method: String"; }

  @SuppressWarnings ("unused")
  private String sampleTest2(Object o) { return "Private Method: Object"; }

  @SuppressWarnings ("unused")
  private String sampleTest3(ArrayList<String> list) { return "Private Method: List<String>"; }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException,
      InstantiationException
  {
    Sample s = new Sample();
    java.lang.reflect.Method method[] = Sample.class.getDeclaredMethods();
    for (int i = 0; i < method.length; i++)
    {
      Method m = method[i];
      if (m.getModifiers() == Modifier.PRIVATE)
      {
        String methodName = m.getName();
        System.out.println(methodName);
        m.setAccessible(true);

        Class<?>[] pType = m.getParameterTypes();
        Object[] params = new Object[pType.length];
        for (int j = 0; j < pType.length; j++)
        {
          params[j] = pType[j].newInstance();
        }
        if (params.length == 0)
        {
          System.out.println(method[i].invoke(s));
        }
        else if (params.length == 1)
        {
          System.out.println(method[i].invoke(s, params[0]));
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

This approach works only if the arguments of the methods have a constructor with no parameters or can be instantiated at all. E. g. `List` is an interface and hence not working, `Double` has a non-nullary c'tor and is also not working etc.

**OUTPUT**

```
sampleTest
Private Method
sampleTest1
Private Method: String
sampleTest2
Private Method: Object
sampleTest3
Private Method: List<String>
```

Answer (score 0):

ITs working

```
Sample s = new Sample();
        java.lang.reflect.Method method [] = Sample.class.getDeclaredMethods();
        System.out.println("Total Number of methods in Sample class"+method.length);
        for(int i=0; i<method.length;i++){
            String methodName=method[i].getName();
            System.out.println("Method Name is "+methodName);
            method[i].setAccessible(true);
            if(methodName.equalsIgnoreCase("sampleTest1")){
            method[i].setAccessible(true);
            //This is calling sampleTest1 method, ITs not workoing
            System.out.println(method[i].invoke(s, new String[]{"ABC"}));
            } else{
            //This is calling sampleTest method its working
            System.out.println(method[i].invoke(s, null));
            }
    }
    }

public class Sample {

    private String sampleTest(){
        return "Private Method";
    }

    private String sampleTest1(String abc){
        return "Private Method "+abc;
    }
}
```

### OUTPUT

Total Number of methods in Sample class2
Method Name is sampleTest1
Private Method ABC
Method Name is sampleTest
Private Method